# How to let Micronaut use a custom TypeConverter from Map to String?

Tags: micronaut

I have created a Micronaut `TypeConverter` (in Kotlin) to convert a map to a cron string for `@Scheduled`, but I can't get Micronaut to do the conversions.

As an example, I want to support the following config:

```
clean:
  cron:
    every: SUN
    at: 01:00:00
```

Which should lead to `0 0 1 * * SUN` (or something like that, I keep making mistakes with these cron strings).

So I created a class in Kotlin that implements this. Micronaut does create an instance of it, but doesn't apply it for conversion:

```
@Singleton
class MapToCron : TypeConverter<Map<String, String>, String>
```

I tried different types (including `Any` and `Map<*, *>`) to no avail.

I also created a @PropertiesConfiguration class that defines this property as a string (I suppose this is required to tell Micronaut what type the property actually is), and injected it into a bean to make sure everything is used (just to be sure, it made no difference).

```
@ConfigurationProperties("clean")
class CleanConfiguration {
    var cron: String? = null
}
```

This: `@Scheduled(cron = "\${clean.cron}")` leads to `Could not resolve placeholder ${clean.cron}`.

To show that the config does get picked up and everything is wired together, `@Scheduled(cron = "\${clean.cron.every}")` leads to `Invalid cron expression [SUN]`, which is correct given the above config.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

What's the motivation behind the custom syntax in the configs? 
If you simply use the standard CRON syntax, Micronaut picks it up flawlessly:

```
clean:
  cron: 0 0 1 * * SUN
```

Comment: Well, of course this works and I didn't pursue this further. I just like the config better than a cron expression. I can't seem to remember where to put which parameter, and readability is pretty bad in my opinion. I realize I'm probably a minority in this respect.